# Render very big UIscrollview UIImage + Video

Tags: ios, performance, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

I'm creating a particular features on my app, and I don't know how's the best way to do that.

I have a `UIScrollview` big as the screen (1024*748). Inside this `UIScrollView` I insert a `UIView`. This view is very big (8000*748) and represent a table. On this table I insert different `UIImageView` and some video. I present this view to the user fitted in the scroll view and then the user can pinch to zoom and to see the video and the image in detail.

I tried 2 different approaches:

1. In the first approach I load all the content of the `UIScrollView` asynchronously and when it's loaded I present it to the user and set the zoom level to 0.4.
2. I then tried to use `CATiledLayer` to have the same behavior of the Google map app, but I have difficulties when I insert Video.

Can anyone tell me what's the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with the first approach?

You say your having trouble with the second approach, so why not use the first approach?

Comment: Because when I zoom out the view it's a little bit slow when scrolled